# repeating the game upon user's request

Tags: java, loops

I'm working on a video poker assignment and having trouble finding a way to to let the player repeat the game. Within the game class, I have two game constructors.
One for when you put any args in the command line:

```
public Game(String[] testHand{
    code...
}
```

Another one for playing a regular game:

```
public Game(){
    code...
}
```

Then in the same class I have a `play()` method that evaluates the player's hand and should ask if the player wants to play again. This is how I have it right now:

```
public void play()
{
    p.sortHand();
    System.out.println(checkHand(p.getHand()));
    if (tokens > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("You have " + tokens + " tokens");
        System.out.println("Play again? Enter yes or no");
        response = input.next();
        if(response.equals("yes"))
        {
            //what do I put here to repeat the whole game to up to here again?
        }
    }   
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
        System.out.println("Your final score is " + tokens + " tokens.");
    }       
}
```

What should I put in the second `if` statement to repeat the game? Here's my test class just in case. I'm not allowed to modify it at all:

```
public class PokerTest {
//this class must remain unchanged
public static void main(String[] args){
    if (args.length<1){
        Game g = new Game();
        g.play();
    }
    else{
        Game g = new Game(args);
        g.play();
    }
}
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: this should not go in the `play` method, as it does not have anything to do with the current play

Comment: But the `play` method has to evaluate the hand, which needs to be done in every separate game. If I include the iteration part within the game method, the hand will never be evaluated before the player chooses whether or not to play again.

Comment: njzk2 is right. Think of it that way: you play a game (this is your `play` method). Then you finish your game (so your method should return). You are then being asked if you want to play again. If your answer is `Yes` you should start the game again (by entering the `play` method).